# How to add Hyphens in UITextField iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

**Need the following format of Numbers with Hyphen when typing in UITextField.**

[image]

Comment: On each text change parse and replace new string with string with hyphens in `UITextField`'s delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

Answer (score 2):

```
// Restrict entry to format 123-456-7890
```

You can try with similar code.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // All digits entered
    if range.location == 12 {
        return false
    }
    // Reject appending non-digit characters
    if range.length == 0 && !NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().characterIsMember(string.characterAtIndex(0)) {
        return false
    }
    // Auto-add hyphen before appending 4rd or 7th digit
    if range.length == 0 && (range.location == 3 || range.location == 7) {
        textField.text = "\(textField.text!)-\(string)"
        return false
    }
    // Delete hyphen when deleting its trailing digit 
    if range.length == 1 && (range.location == 4 || range.location == 8) {
        range.location--
        range.length = 2
        textField.text = textField.text!.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: "")
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```